# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() for categorical columns

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the sum of a column based on a condition on another categorical column.

I tried to use `str.contains()` but got no solution either.

The Type column has either Equal or not equal values.
The `COUNT(Z.GENERATE_BUYLEAD)` column is numerical.
The `DIR_QUERY_MCATID` column is basically the unique ids.
The `BUYER_CITY` column has city names.
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foK5O.png)

```
def calc(x):
    if x['Type']=="Equal":
        sum_equal = x['COUNT(Z.GENERATE_BUYLEAD)'].sum()
    else:
        None
    final_percent = (sum_equal*100)/x['COUNT(Z.GENERATE_BUYLEAD)'].sum()
    return final_percent

dec['percent'] = dec.groupby(['DIR_QUERY_MCATID','BUYER_CITY']).apply(lambda x: calc(x))
```

I need to get the ratio of `COUNT(Z.GENERATE_BUYLEAD)` column if Type column contains `Equal`, divided by the sum of all the values in `COUNT(Z.GENERATE_BUYLEAD)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `x['Type']=="Equal"` wont return just one value. Its is returning multiple values. When you pass a condition to the `if` statement, you need to make sure that the condition will result in a singular `True` or `False`.

The `x['Type']=="Equal"` statement returns you a collection(`pd.Series`) of `True` and `False`. So the error message is basically telling you to try to make it a single `True`/`False` perhaps by using any one of the functions it mentions in the error message.

You will have to change your condition to comply with the python functions.
Also, there are other ways to accomplish what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly I believe this is what you are looking for. You subset the dataframe by `Type` column and get the sum and then divide it by the total sum. This is what I think you are trying to do with your `if` statement.

Using your data given in your example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = [[39484, 'Chennai', 2, 2, 'Chennai', 'Equal'],
      [5957, 'Hyderabad', 1, 1, 'Chennai', 'Not Equal'],
      [22932, 'Burhanput', 1, 1, 'Vadodara', 'Not Equal'],
      [176584, 'Hyderabad', 1, 1, 'Vadodara', 'Not Equal'],
      [2781, 'Mumbai', 1, 1, 'Vadodara', 'Not Equal'],
     ]
cols = ['dir_query_mcatid', 'buyer_city', 'count(z.generate_buylead)',
        'count(z.purchase_buylead)', 'seller_city', 'type']

test = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=cols)
def calc(x):
    sum_equal = x[x['type'] == 'Equal']['count(z.generate_buylead)'].sum()
    final_percent = (sum_equal*100)/x['count(z.generate_buylead)'].sum()
    return final_percent

new = test.groupby(['dir_query_mcatid','buyer_city']).apply(lambda x: calc(x)).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'percent'})
test = test.merge(new, on=['dir_query_mcatid', 'buyer_city'])
print(test)
```

Which gives this output:

```
  dir_query_mcatid buyer_city  count(z.generate_buylead)  \
0             39484    Chennai                          2   
1              5957  Hyderabad                          1   
2             22932  Burhanput                          1   
3            176584  Hyderabad                          1   
4              2781     Mumbai                          1   

   count(z.purchase_buylead) seller_city       type  percent  
0                          2     Chennai      Equal    100.0  
1                          1     Chennai  Not Equal      0.0  
2                          1    Vadodara  Not Equal      0.0  
3                          1    Vadodara  Not Equal      0.0  
4                          1    Vadodara  Not Equal      0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this was what I was looking for. But on running the above code I am getting an error saying "ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'" and also "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"

Comment: @J.Doe I've updated the code to give a more robust answer

Comment: @J.Doe can you please accept the answer if this solved your problem thanks.